# Why is the spelling of "pronounce" and "pronunciation" different?

Tags: etymology, verbs, nouns, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Why is the spelling of *pronounce* and *pronunciation* different? If one originally did not know the spelling of *pronunciation*, one would when hearing it verbally deduce its spelling to be *pronounciation*, which is the incorrect spelling.

Why is the difference in spelling so? Also, are the two words pronounced differently? (I think I am using the American pronunciation for *pronunciation* (*pro-noun-ciation*), but according to [howjsay.com](http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=pronunciation;pronounce&submit=Submit), it's pronounced as *pro-nun-ciation*. Is this just for British English or universally?)

Comment: I wish I had a dollar for every time I've found myself typing "pronounciation" and had to back up to spell it correctly. My fingers seem wired to a misspelling and no amount of repetition seems to help.

Comment: The two words are pronounced the way they are spelt - in most versions of English. I think it is just the Americans who changed it.

Comment: @Rory: the Americans changed what? Americans pronounce these words the way they are spelled, as well.

Comment: @PeterShor that's not true in general.

Comment: Related: [Why did the letter “o” disappear in the word “pronunciation”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217014), [What is it called phonetically, when Americans change the pronunciation of “pronunciation” to “pro-*noun*-ciation”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29103)

Comment: I'm an American and have never heard anyone say "proNOUNciation". I've always heard pronunciation spoken as it is spelled. And I'm 47 years old.

Comment: @iMerchant -- 67 years old and pretty much the same, except that I have heard E2L speakers mispronunce the word at times.

Comment: Pro-noun-ciation has had a toehold at least since the first half of the 20th century, but it must vary regionally and with other factors.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*pro-NOUN-ciation* is universally wrong. Even the highly permissive Merriam-Webster dictionary [marks it with an obelus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pronunciation) (÷). Here is what they say about pronunciations marked with an obelus:

> The obelus, or division sign, is placed before a pronunciation variant that occurs in educated speech but that is considered by some to be questionable or unacceptable. This symbol is used sparingly and primarily for variants that have been objected to over a period of time in print by commentators on usage, in schools by teachers, or in correspondence that has come to the Merriam-Webster editorial department. In most cases the objection is based on orthographic or etymological arguments. ([source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/help/pronguide.htm))

As for *why* the word *pronounce* has an O between the two N’s and *pronunciation* does not, it is unclear, but both words derive from French, *pronunciation* from *pronunciation* and *pronounce* from *pronuncier*. There is probably some variation in the way the different word stress affected how the words were spelled after being borrowed into English.

Comment: (The French is misspelled, it's _prononcer_ and _prononciation_.)

Comment: @Mat You seem to have got that, where from? Can you give some useful leads to *prononcer* and *prononciation*?

Comment: @Kris: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/prononcer, http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/prononciation

Comment: @Mat, it should be _prononcier_, since we’re talking about Old French, not Modern French.

Comment: So it is "a pronunciation variant that occurs in educated speech". Not wrong. I'm a proud user of  "proNOUNciation" myself.

Answer (score 20):

[Trisyllabic laxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisyllabic_laxing) is the reason for the pronunciation difference, which led to the spelling difference.

Comment: This is actually the most well informed answer.

Answer (score 2):

English words descended from Latin "*nuntiare* ('to announce')" are non-uniform. I've **bolded** the irregularities:

pronounce |  pronunciation | **pronounciation** | **pronouncement** | x

announce  | annunciation **(archaic)** | x | **announcement** |x

denounce  |  denunciation |  x | x | x

renounce   | renunciation | x | x | x

**X** | enunciation | x | x | **enunciate**

It is scarcely more defensible to say that "*pronounciation*" is wrong than to say that "*enunciate*" should be replaced by "*enounce*" or "*announcement*" by the more venerable "*annunciation*".

**Contra the top answer, *pro-NOUN-ciation* is a fine pron(o)unciation**, as it is common and easily-understood. It may be regretted by sticklers, but this is the way millions of native speakers say it.

The spelling "*pronounciation*", however, faces intractable stigma (spelling variants are generally tolerated less than pronunciation variants). It is best avoided in formal writing.

Comment: The second part of your answer is absolutely correct, but the first paragraph is misleading. The spelling is stigmatised, but so is the pronunciation. Both are exceedingly common and easily understood; that doesn't mean they're not stigmatised. The fact that M-W marks the pronunciation with an obelus is evidence that it is in fact stigmatised in the eyes of many people. Incidentally, you'll notice that in your ‘table’, _-nounciation_ is the only form that does not exist at all as a primary form—unlike the other four, it exists **only** as a (stigmatised) variant.

Comment: The occurrence of the spelling "pronounciation" in published prose is negligible compared to the the spelling "pronunciation" https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pronunciation%2Cpronounciation&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpronunciation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpronounciation%3B%2Cc0

Comment: By contrast the pronunciation "pro-NOUN-ciation" is the primary form for millions of native English speakers. Yes, it is minorly stigmatized, but so are, e.g. many US Southern accents. I don't think it would be misleading to characterize Southern US variant pronunciations as "fine" however.

Comment: You cannot compare edited, published works with spontaneous speech. If you can find evidence that the spelling is negligible compared to the pronunciation in pre-studied speech (plays, newsreaders, etc.), that might be a reasonable comparison; but if you're comparing natural speech (the default), you should compare it to spontaneous writing (_without_ autocorrect and spellcheckers, crucially). The spelling with an o is also primary to many people.

Comment: I'm not necessarily saying the pronunciation with an o isn't fine; I'm saying there's no real basis for saying that the pronunciation is fine and the spelling in contrast is stigmatised, juxtaposing _fine_ and _stigmatised_ and thereby implicitly saying that the pronunciation is not stigmatised and the spelling is not fine. Both are stigmatised and best avoided in formal contexts where stigmatisation may be an issue; and if you ask me, both are perfectly fine for informal purposes.

Comment: I was juxtaposing "fine" and "widely stigmatized". I've switched the wording since the stigma on the pronunciation may indeed be wide, but it is not as severe or settled. My claim is that there is a large difference in the severity of stigma between the pronunciation and the spelling in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58764/discussion-between-colin-zwanziger-and-janus-bahs-jacquet).

Answer (score -1):

Both words have different roots, as shown by [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com). That could be the reason why they are spelled & *pronounced* differently.

**pronunciation:**

> early 15c., "mode in which a word is pronounced," from L.
>   pronuntiationem (nom. pronuntiatio)
>   "act of speaking,"

**pronounce:**

> early 14c., "to utter, declare officially," from O.Fr. pronuncier
>   (late 13c.), from L.L. pronunciare,
>   from L. pronuntiare "to proclaim,
>   announce, pronounce," from pro-
>   "forth, out, in public" (see pro-) +
>   nuntiare "announce," from nuntius
>   "messenger" (see nuncio).

As a side note, I have not encountered anyone using "pro-NOUN-ciation", but then again, I'm not from the US.

Comment: No, they are from the same root (pronuntio), but the longer word was adopted directly from Latin, as a learned word, but the shorter one came from French, where the vowel had already changed from the Latin original.

Comment: Where's the *o* in either of the sources? How then are they 'different roots'?

Comment: @ColinFine That's not relevant, at least one of the claimed 'roots' should have had an *o* in it? Else where's the argument here?

Comment: BTW, the use of *both* in *Both words have different ...* is incorrect.

Comment: @Kris, etymonline apoears to have corrected and expanded these entries since 2010. They now have o’s in both words (both from Old French, neither directly from Latin).

Answer (score -1):

I find it easier to use the short u sound in the second syllable of pronunciation. We spell it the way we say it, of course. "Of course" ? Huh! ;-/