# What is it called phonetically, when Americans change the pronunciation of "pronunciation" to "pro-*noun*-ciation"?

Tags: pronunciation

I used to have quite a bit of trouble spelling the word *pronunciation* because it's a long word, and because the way I pronounce it misleads me — I say "pro-noun-ciation" instead of "pro-nun-ciation". What would a phoneticist say I was doing when I change the quality of the vowel?

Comment: Do Americans in general pronounce it like you? (I don't think so) If not, and there's no general use like that, isn't this a bit localized?

Comment: @Mitch - It's neither a general American pronunciation nor a regional one; it **is**, however, a common error - common enough that saying something like "Pardon my mispronounciation" is a fairly common, humorous way to acknowledge that you've just (for instance) mangled someone's name.  Everyone knows it's wrong; I've never met anyone who _intentionally_ said "pronounciation" except in a humorous context... but it does seem to be a fairly common error; I would estimate that it's said (accidentally) perhaps 3-5% of the times that "pronunciation" is intended. Do only USAites make this mistake?

Comment: I don't recall noticing this mistake in British speakers but as a spelling error it's very common.  In fact, I almost always have to stop at the second *n* and correct myself when typing this word.

Comment: I most definitely have noticed this mistake in British speakers, both in how it is spelled and pronounced. I have no idea how common it is though. Oddly I don't know how common it is in Australia either even though that's where I'm from.

Comment: I've noticed something similar with Danish speakers.  The word for vikings is vikinger, which is pronounced with a VEE sound, yet when they go to pronounce 'vikings' in English it becomes (more often than not) WHYkings.

Comment: @MT_Head It's not a speech error, but rather the primary pronunciation for many native English speakers.

Comment: @ColinZwanziger Citation please?

Comment: consider the fact that the OP and the OP of this post https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5732/why-is-the-spelling-of-pronounce-and-pronunciation-different both say it that way. The reason it is a common misspelling is because so many people say it that way and are "spelling it like it sounds". In the post I am linking M-W describes it as a "variant that occurs in educated speech"

Comment: What's it called when Australians do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a phonologically-defined vowel change, unless you have a list of words with a similar phonological pattern.

Instead, what you are doing with *pro-nounc-iation* is maintaining the structure of the stem, *pronounce*, instead of allowing it to undergo a vowel reduction ([aʊ] -> [ʌ]).  (Incidentally, the vowel reduction occurs in the first place because that syllable, which is stressed in the verb *pronounce* becomes unstressed in the word *pronunciation*; of course, we aren't recreating this reduction every time we pronounce the word — the reduction became "set" in that word in the lexicon at some point in time.)

In any case, keeping the stem constant as you are doing could be considered a form of [leveling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_leveling).  That is, you are regularizing the stem analogically, thus keeping the stem constant across different derivational forms.

Comment: I agree with your answer: this is leveling that maintains the stem.  But I disagree when you say the rest of us aren't recreating the reduction every time we pronounce the word.  I'm pretty sure I would do the same [aʊ] -> [ʌ] reduction for nonce words with -ation suffix, such as razlound->razlundation, spennouct->spennuctation

Comment: @krubo: Even if you would do that, it certainly doesn't mean that the word *pronunciation* isn't lexicalized.

Comment: The second syllable of "pronunciation" does not have a reduced vowel for me; I am pretty sure it doesn't for most people. It has secondary stress. The vowel change is a separate phenomenon from reduction, like the shift between "serene" and "serenity."

Comment: @sumelic: You are right. Looking at this five years later I am not sure what I was thinking!

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is called **analogy**: because a similar word in similar circumstances is pronounced with ou, some speakers will pronounce the u in *pronunciation* likewise, and its sound may eventually change completely. See Wikipedia on *[analogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogy#Linguistics)* in linguistics. Variation (often by contraction) and analogy are the great opposing forces that continually mould our language into new forms.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the scale of the change, it could be considered a [vowel shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_shift):

> A vowel shift is a systematic sound change in the pronunciation of the vowel sounds of a language.

The specific vowel shift that hits home for me is the [Northern cities vowel shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Cities_Vowel_Shift):

> - Raising and tensing of /æ/
> - Fronting of /ɑ/
> - Lowering of /ɔ/
> - Backing and lowering of /ɛ/
> - Backing of /ʌ/
> - Lowering and backing of /ɪ/

Notice that there are specific terms used to describe the individual changes. Moving from "nun" to "noun" would probably line up with this description and therefore receive the term "backing":

> Backing of /ʌ/ — The movement of /ʌ/ toward [ɔ]. /ʌ/ is the "short u" vowel, as in cut. People with the shift pronounce cut so that it sounds more like caught to people without the shift.

Comment: This isn't a vowel shift if it happens with one word — it should occur with lots of words in similar contexts. It clearly looks like a morphological issue (i.e. stem alternation, or lack thereof) and not a phonological one.

Comment: @Kosmonaut, perhaps your comment should be an independent answer? It seems to me to be quite a reasonable explanation.

Comment: @jyc23: Actually I just finished composing my answer :)

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Without more information, it wouldn't be possible to tell if this is happening to other words around Billare. But yeah, very good point.

Answer (score 0):

There may be

- general population phonetic reasons (vowel shifting)
- cultural reasons (just people around you say it that way)
- a folk etymology may be influencing you, that is, knowing that the longer word 'pronunciation' is possibly a derivative of 'pronounce', you (and your surroundings) also pronounce the derived word 'pronounce-iation'