# Why did the letter “o” disappear in the word “pronunciation”?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, history, pronunciation-vs-spelling

The verb *pro**nounc**e* has the letter *o* in its second syllable, but in the noun *pro**nunc**iation*, that same letter disappears from the corresponding position.

Why is that?

Comment: Because writing represents speech, not the other way around. The real word is /prənənsi'yeʃən/, and the various vowels are artifacts of how it used to be pronounced in other languages. It is the spoken language that is real; written English is simply a bad attempt to represent Middle English that we're stuck with because it has too much installed base. Kind of like Windows, only 500 years old. Moral: **DON'T** expect the spelling of an English word to have any systematic relation to its pronunciation.

Comment: I don't have an answer to this, but it is hilarious that we mispronounce pronounciation.

Comment: And mispell misspelling.

Comment: @JohnLawler Hmm, but your ignoring a well-known relationship between two vowels in English. Your transcription's not quite there, imo. I think you need this: /prən**ʌ**nsi'eɪʃn/

Comment: That's another variant. People pronounce things differently. You even pronounce things differently, from time to time and body state to body state. Pronunciation is a body function. Worrying about one "correct" transcription is like worrying about a patient's blood pressure when it varies from hour to hour.

Comment: @JohnLawler Hmm, the only reason I'm saying is because your transcription gives a schwa in a syllable which carries secondary stress ... But maybe there's no underlying stress there in your pronunciation? Re "correct" pron, I have no hang-ups about "correct" pronunciation :D

Comment: It's phonemic. A shwa in any unstressed syllable can decay to [ɨ] or to a syllabic resonant, or disappear entirely, at fast enough speech rates. Phonemic transcriptions don't try to account for that; that's what phonetics is for. Generally when articulating, I use shwa /ə/ to transcribe an unstressed central(ized) vowel, and also to transcribe a stressed [∧]; they're in complementary distribution, after all.

Comment: The older way was more difficult in the pronunciation.

Comment: Actually, it went away during the Great O Famine of 1642.

Comment: @JohnLawler Point taken

Comment: I have now added some important information from the Oxford English Dictionary to my post. This shows, that, in fact, there WAS an 'O' in many of the early spellings of the word 'pronunciation'!!! :D

Comment: @DanielSank: Shouldn't we be finding it hilarious that we ***mispronunce pronounciation**?*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The direct answer to your immediate question is because it never had one — and so of course it couldn’t possibly lose something it never had.

The problem is that you’ve asked a bit of a backwards question; the frontwards question is:

> Why did *pronunciation, annunciation, enunciation, renunciation* all change their vowel for the verbs *pronounce, announce, enounce, renounce*?

The answer lies in how we acquired them from Old French, where the verbs already had Latin’s *u* changed to *o* and which we later diphthonged, but where the differently stressed nouns did not.

More recent exports — well, or envoys — from Rome that didn’t pass through France suffered no such frobnication; just ask your nearest *papal nuncio*.

Here are the OED’s etymology entries for these:

> ### pronounce
>
> ME. *pronunce, pronounce*, a. OFr. *pronuncier* (1277 in Godef. Compl.), for earlier *purnuncier* (mod.Fr. *prononcer*) :– late L. *prōnunciāre* for orig. *prōnuntiāre* to proclaim, announce, rehearse, narrate, pronounce, f. *prō*, <sub><sup>**PRO**</sup></sub><sup>1</sup> + *nunti-āre* to announce: cf. <sub><sup>**ANNOUNCE**</sup></sub>, <sub><sup>**ENOUNCE**</sup></sub>.
>
> ### announce
>
> a. OFr. *anonce-r*, earlier *anoncier*, *anuncier* :– L. *adnuntiā-re,* f. *ad* to + *nuntiāre* to bear a message, f. *nunti-us* bringing news. See <sub><sup>**AN-**</sup></sub> *pref.* <sup>6</sup>.
>
> ### enounce
>
> ad. Fr. *énoncer*, ad. L. *ēnuntiā-re* (see <sub><sup>**ENUNCIATE**</sup></sub>), after the analogy of <sub><sup>**ANNOUNCE**</sup></sub>.
>
> ### renounce
>
> ad. Fr. *renoncer* (OFr. also *renuncer*) :– L. *renuntiāre* (-*ciāre*) to announce, proclaim, also to disclaim, protest against, f. *re-* re- + *nuntiāre* to make known, report: cf. <sub><sup>**ANNOUNCE**</sup></sub>, <sub><sup>**DENOUNCE**</sup></sub>, etc.
>
> ### nuncio
>
> a. earlier Ital. *nuncio, nuntio* (now *nunzio*), = Sp. and Pg. *nuncio* :– L. *nuncius, nuntius* messenger.

Understand that this is the same thing that happened to Latin *uncia* meaning one-twelfth part of something, which coming to us by way of Old French eventually gave us an *ounce*, twelve of which make a troy pound.

However, the more direct borrowing from the Latin *uncia* into Old English itself was *ynch*, a different vowel that ultimately became *inch*, twelve of which make a foot.

There is also the *ounce* that means lynx, but that word traces a slightly different route between Latin and English, having confused the leading *l-* for an article and therefore losing it, much as *a napron* became *an apron* over a confusion about articles, just as occurred with *an orange* which originally had a leading *n-* in the noun.

Comment: But if you've checked in the OED, then you'll know that this word has been spelled with an 'O' at many times during its history -please see other answers here.

Answer (score 28):

The answer to this question is that the 'O' got squashed out of the root by  "*rhythmic clipping*".

First of all, one might think that there has never been an 'O' in the word *pronunciation*. In fact, the truth is rather different! Before the advent of dictionaries and word-processing spell-checkers, this word was often spelled with an 'O' in the second syllable. In fact the Oxford English Dictionary (not the Oxford Dictionary Online), gives five historical alternative spellings for *pronunciation* with an 'O' in the second syllable. One of these, it says, is still current, though not considered "standard". Here they are. The digits before the word indicate the centuries that spelling was used in. The third one in is meant to be current (1500s to the present day), though nonstandard:

> - 15 pronouncyacyon, 15–16 pronounciacion, 15– pronounciation (now nonstandard), 16 prononciation, 16 pronountiation.

The rest of this answer is dedicated to why the letter 'O' is missing from this word in the modern spelling.

Let's consider the word *pronounce*.  When we say this word, it is with an /aʊ/ sound in the stressed syllable. One of the typical spellings for this sound in the orthography is the sequence 'OU'. We can see this spelling-sound correspondence in the following words:

- a**bound**
- pro**found**
- **found**
- **south**

This vowel, /aʊ/, is often called the *MOUTH* vowel by phoneticians and phonologists. This vowel has a special relationship with the *STRUT* vowel, /ʌ/. The *STRUT* vowel is the vowel found in the words *up, flood,* and *buck*. This vowel is often found in words with the same root as words with the *MOUTH* vowel. Here are some examples:

- a**bun**dance
- pro**fun**dity
- re**fund**
- **south**ern

Sometimes this change of vowel in the base is reflected in the spelling. This usually means that the *STRUT* vowel is represented by the letter "U". This is the case with the example words *abundance, profundity, refund* above. Because of the vagaries of English spelling, it isn't represented in the word *Southern*.

We might think that this is some random relationship. However, the vowel /aʊ/ is a diphthong. This means that it belongs to a family of vowels which may be characterised as being "long".

There seems to be a systematic relationship between many long vowels in English and other specific short vowels. If you speak English, these qualities will seem to be logical. In fact, they aren't. In terms of the actual sound there is almost no phonetic relationship between the long vowels and their short vowel counterparts. For example, the vowels in the words *weight* and *bad* are not very similar. We represent these sounds by the symbols: /eɪ/ and /æ/ respectively. However, these vowels have a very close relationship in the language. For example, the following words have the /eɪ/ vowel:

- **grate**ful
- **sane**
- in**flame**

The following words, on the other hand, even though they have the same root, usually have the vowel /æ/:

- **grat**itude
- in**san**ity
- in**flam**atory

This change from long to short vowels usually happens when there are extra syllables added to the base or root of the word. The more syllables there are in a word the more short vowels and the less long vowels we are likely to see. [This is a result of  *rhythmic clipping*. This is when the vowels in the base of a word get shorter when extra syllables are added.] The following long and short vowels have this same relationship:

- eɪ / æ
- i: / e
- aɪ / ɪ
- əʊ / ɒ
- aʊ / ʌ

These relationships can be seen in the pairs of words respectively:

- **chaste** / **chas**tity
- **pen**al / **pen**itentiary
- **wise** / **wis**dom
- **joke** / **joc**ular
- **south** / **south**ern

Note that the spelling of words may reflect common ways of enunciating them, for example:

- pron**ou**nce / pron**u**nciation

In this example, as described above, we see alternation between /aʊ/ and /ʌ/. This is reflected in the corresponding spellings of "ou" and "u" respectively. However, it should still be noted, that this is because the spelling must reflect some type of pronunciation in the original instance. It is still the case that there are also alternative pronunciations. Very importantly, *pronunciation* may be pronounced /prə**nʌn**sieɪʃn/ or /prə**naʊn**sieɪʃn/. Both ways of saying the word are perfectly fine, but the spelling reflects the first, not the second.

This is not the case for all alternations. For example we cannot say:

- w**aɪ**zdəm [wise dom]

for:

- w**ɪ**zdəm [wiz dom]

The sorter /ɪ/ vowel must be used in the longer word.

**The Original Poster's question**

The 'O' in *pronounce* disappears in the word *pronunciation* because it reflects a common change in the pronunciation of the English word, when we add more syllables to the base. Usually, in this case, the *STRUT* vowel replaces the *MOUTH* vowel for many speakers. However, this does not mean that the pronunciation of the second vowel in the word will change for *all* speakers. The retention of the full /aʊ/ vowel is also quite frequent in standard English.

The reason that this happens is that certain long and short vowels have a special phonological relationship in English. The vowels /aʊ/ and /ʌ/, *MOUTH* and *STRUT* are two such vowels and their spelling is often reflected in English orthography by the letters *ou* or *u*. However, sometimes many speakers still use the *MOUTH* vowel for words with a *u* spelling. This is perfectly fine!

For the record, English spelling is not systematic or well organised.

Hope this is helpful!

**References**: "pronunciation, n." OED Online. Oxford University Press, December 2014. Web. 28 December 2014.

Comment: The relationship between these vowels is that, before the [Great Vowel Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift), the *MOUTH* vowel was a long *STRUT* vowel, the *WEIGHT* vowel was a long *BAD* vowel, and so forth. And in the Great Vowel Shift, the long vowels were changed dramatically (and the short ones slightly), so that they are now phonetically quite distant from the corresponding short ones.

Comment: @PeterShor and the STRUT vowel also changed. In fact, STRUT was originally pronounced with a BOOK vowel, whose long counterpart would be MOON, the old pronunciation of MOUTH (Old English mūþ).

Comment: +1, this is a very good answer. However, I don't like that you wrote with no further comment “Very importantly, pronunciation may be pronounced /prənʌnsieɪʃn/ or /prənaʊnsieɪʃn/. Both ways of saying the word are perfectly fine, but the spelling reflects the first, not the second.” I get that we don’t want to make people feel bad about their idiolects, but there are a significant amount of people who would consider /prənaʊnsieɪʃn/ a solecism, and I think it's good for people who are learning how to pronounce English to be aware of this.

Comment: @sumelic Yes, I'm kindof in two minds about that. I think if I was writing on ELL, I'd definitely make a point out of that. Here on EL&U I'm not so sure. I was at an English phonetics conference last year and there were several prestigious phoneticians speaking. At least two speakers said /prənaʊnsieɪʃn/ during their talks ( accidentally, I'm sure). At my school I hear it all the time from SSBE speaking teachers. It's rampant! At the time my reaction was to chortle gleefully at the speakers - but having reflected on it, that was rather unfair ...

Comment: @sumelic because those speakers would never look down on someone else's pronunciation of an item. Anyhow I now reckon that it's so widespread  it can't really be put down to freak idiolects really ... Will think some more.

Comment: Well, I just discovered that ELU even has a question about this pronunciation already: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29103/what-is-it-called-phonetically-when-americans-change-the-pronunciation-of-pron

Comment: @sumelic It's interesting isn't it. There are other words where we see variation between the longer and shorter members of the pair. One example that comes to mind is *privacy* where some speakers use /ɪ/ and others /aɪ/. The difference here is that the spelling does not give one particular party an edge in terms of being "proper", so I'm wondering if the spelling has marginalised what might otherwise be considered a normal or accepted alternative pronunciation?

Answer (score 2):

While this probably doesn't add significant new content to the answers already provided, it seems useful to reproduce here the [comments from *Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pronunciation#note-1) on this issue:

> Both the noun and verb come ultimately from the Latin verb *pronuntiare*. But when the Latin verb was taken into Anglo-French and later entered Middle English, that second vowel was sometimes rendered as *-u-* and sometimes rendered as *-ou-*. This meant that, from about the 1500s onward, we have evidence of both *pronounciation* and *pronunciation* in the written record. Eventually the noun standardized to *pronunciation*, but because of influence from *pronounce*, we do occasionally see *pronounciation* in print, and we also have evidence of a corresponding pronunciation for *pronounciation* (\pruh-nown-see-AY-shun). The spelling *pronounciation* and the pronunciation that goes with that spelling are not considered a part of standard English. Using them could result in criticism or questioning.

Answer (score 1):

We usually append the suffix [*-tion*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-tion) to verbs in order to make them nouns.

So *pronounce* (verb) + *tion* -> *pronounciation*.

But why is it written without an 'O' in the second syllable (even though the verb it derived from does have an 'O')?

[Trisyllabic Laxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisyllabic_laxing) is the reason 'pronounciation' lost its O and became *pronunciation*. It's a process whereby a tense vowel is shortened if two (or more) syllables follow.

**Examples:**

- Profane, profanity --- /prəˈf**eɪ**n/ -> /prəˈf**æ**n.ə.ti/
- Impede, impediment --- /ɪmˈp**iː**d/ -> /ɪmˈp**e**d.ɪ.mənt/
- Divine, divinity --- /dɪˈv**aɪ**n/ -> /dɪˈv**ɪ**n.ə.ti/
- Profound, profundity --- /prəˈf**aʊ**nd/ -> /prəˈf**ʌ**n.də.ti/
- Pronounce, pronunciation --- /prəˈn**aʊ**ns/ -> /prəˌn**ʌ**n.siˈeɪ.ʃən/

Trisyllabic Laxing caused the pronunciation of 'pronounciation' to change which influenced the spelling.

---

OR

*Pronounce* is stressed on the second syllable, but when we append the suffix *-tion*, the primary stress moves to the penult. Words that end with *-tion* are usually stressed on the penultimate syllable.

The /aʊ/ diphthong (as in the word 'pronounce') seems to have a systematic relationship with the *STRUT* vowel /ʌ/ (as explained in Araucaria's answer and also explained in Trisyllabic Laxing)

When we add syllables, the vowels get laxed (shortened) and the /aʊ/ is likely to change to the /ʌ/ vowel.

Therefore, when we add the suffix *-tion* to the word 'pronounce', the primary stress moves to the penult and we get the /ʌ/ vowel in the second syllable of *pronunciation*.

**Why does the O get removed from the second syllable of 'pronounciation'?**

It's probably because we have the /ʌ/ vowel in the second syllable and the digraph  <ou> in Modern English does not often represent the /ʌ/ vowel (there are a *couple* of exceptions though). So we remove the 'O' to match the spelling and pronunciation.

Comment: Wow, late to the party, but still, seems like a greatly understandable grammatical process.