# Why is it spelt "pronunciation"?

Tags: orthography

Interestingly I couldn't find a similar existing question here, so I'll ask. Why is "pronunciation" spelt thus if the root word is "pronounce", with an "o"? In other words, why is it not "pronounciation", as some people are inclined to write (and say)?

Comment: Hi Dog Lover! Of interest: [Why is the spelling of “pronounce” and “pronunciation” different?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5732/why-is-the-spelling-of-pronounce-and-pronunciation-different)

Comment: I'm going to say (with others) that it is a duplicate. If it isn't, DogLover, please edit this question to make the difference clear.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think [this question here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217014/why-did-the-letter-o-disappear-in-the-word-pronunciation/217098#217098) might be a better dupe to link to (even if one of the answers is mine! ... :)) The reason is that the answers address the *why* in the OP's question here - as opposed to just *whether*.

Comment: @Lawrence Thank you. I'm surprised that didn't show up in my search. I thought it was odd that there was no similar question.